# No Zend\Validator\Alnum in ZF2 Library. Where can I find it?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-validate

I've downloaded ZF2 framework but there is no `Zend\Validator\Alnum` class in `\library\Zend\Validator` directory. But the manual says it must be there:

```
// Basic usage
// A basic example is the following one:

$validator = new Zend\Validator\Alnum();
if ($validator->isValid('Abcd12')) {
    // value contains only allowed chars
} else {
    // false
}
```

Is this normal or they've changed their framework but forgot to change manual? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the alnum validator in the i18n component:

```
new Zend\I18n\Validator\Alnum():
```